# Loading a jdbc driver in a java class

Tags: jdbc

In a simple jdbc example , when we load a driver through a java class, the practise is to use  `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();`
Why we do not use `new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code isn't really intended to create an instance of the driver but to ensure the driver class is loaded by the class loader. Nowadays this is no longer needed, see:

- [What is the actual use of Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") while connecting to a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053095)
- [JDBC Class.forName vs DriverManager.registerDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484227)
- [Loading JDBC driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992126)
- [What is the purpose of 'Class.forName("MY_JDBC_DRIVER")'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662902)
- [JDBC connection- Class.forName vs Class.forName().newInstance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640268)