# Java - Getting Data from MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jsp

I've connected to a MySQL database, which contains four fields (the first of which being an ID, the latter ones each containing varchar strings).

I am trying to get the last row of the database and retrieve the contents of the fields so that I can set them to variables (an int and three strings) and use them later.

So far, I have the bare minimum to make the connection, where do I go from here? As you can see I have tried to write a SQL statement to get the last row but it's all gone wrong from there and I don't know how to split it into the separate fields.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/t", "", "");

Statement st = con.createStatement();
String sql = ("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;");
st.getResultSet().getRow();
con.close();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here you go :

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/t", "", "");

Statement st = con.createStatement();
String sql = ("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;");
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
if(rs.next()) { 
 int id = rs.getInt("first_column_name"); 
 String str1 = rs.getString("second_column_name");
}

con.close();
```

In `rs.getInt` or `rs.getString` you can pass `column_id` starting from `1`, but i prefer to pass `column_name` as its more informative as you don't have to look at database `table` for which `index` is what `column`.

**UPDATE :** `rs.next`

> boolean next()
>                throws SQLException
>
> Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position. A
>   ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the
>   first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the
>   second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.
>
> When a call to the next method returns false, the cursor is positioned
>   after the last row. Any invocation of a ResultSet method which
>   requires a current row will result in a SQLException being thrown. If
>   the result set type is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, it is vendor specified
>   whether their JDBC driver implementation will return false or throw an
>   SQLException on a subsequent call to next.
>
> If an input stream is open for the current row, a call to the method
>   next will implicitly close it. A ResultSet object's warning chain is
>   cleared when a new row is read.
>
> Returns:
>       true if the new current row is valid; false if there are no more rows Throws:
>       SQLException - if a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed result set

[reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29)

Answer (score 3):

Something like this would do:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/t";
    String user = "";
    String password = "";

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;");

        if (rs.next()) {//get first result
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));//coloumn 1
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, ex.getMessage(), ex);

    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) {
                rs.close();
            }
            if (st != null) {
                st.close();
            }
            if (con != null) {
                con.close();
            }

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(Version.class.getName());
            lgr.log(Level.WARNING, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

you can iterate over the results with a `while` like this:

```
while(rs.next())
{
System.out.println(rs.getString("Colomn_Name"));//or getString(1) for coloumn 1 etc
}
```

There are many other great tutorial out there like these to list a few:

- http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html
- http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=9

As for your use of `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();` see [JDBC connection- Class.forName vs Class.forName().newInstance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640268/jdbc-connection-class-forname-vs-class-forname-newinstance) which shows how you can just use `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` as its not necessary to initiate it yourself

**References:**

- http://zetcode.com/databases/mysqljavatutorial/

Answer (score 1):

This should work, I think...

```
ResultSet results = st.executeQuery(sql);

if(results.next()) { //there is a row
 int id = results.getInt(1); //ID if its 1st column
 String str1 = results.getString(2);
 ...
}
```

Comment: Why does results.next() let us kknow that there is a row?

Comment: It moves to the next row available (initially it's before the first row), if there's none it returns false, so it fails; otherwise it returns true and it continues.

Comment: also have a [look](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Easy Java method to get data from MySQL table:

```
/*
 * CREDIT : WWW.CODENIRVANA.IN
*/

String Data(String query){
    String get=null;
    try{

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
Connection con = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection
("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","password");
Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
if (rs.next())
       {
get = rs.getString("");
        }

}
catch(Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, e.getMessage());
}
    return get;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I just did right now:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.sun.javafx.runtime.VersionInfo;  

public class ConnectToMySql {
public static ConnectBean dataBean = new ConnectBean();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    getData();
    }



public static void getData () {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mynewpage", 
 "root", "root");
        
 // here mynewpage is database name, root is username and password
    
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        System.out.println("stmt  " + stmt);
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from carsData");
        System.out.println("rs  " + rs);
        int count = 1;
        while (rs.next()) {
            String vehicleType = rs.getString("VHCL_TYPE");
            System.out.println(count  +": " + vehicleType);
            count++;

        }

        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logger lgr = Logger.getLogger(VersionInfo.class.getName());
        lgr.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    
    
}

}
```

The Above code will get you the first column of the table you have.

This is the table which you might need to create in your MySQL database

```
CREATE TABLE
carsData
(
    VHCL_TYPE CHARACTER(10) NOT NULL,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

- First, Download MySQL connector jar file, This is the latest jar file as of today [[mysql-connector-java-8.0.21]](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/mysql/mysql-connector-java).
- Add the Jar file to your workspace [build path].
- Then Create a new Connection object from the DriverManager class, so you could use this Connection object to execute queries.
- Define the database name, userName, and Password for your connection.
- Use the resultSet to get the data based one the column name from your database table.

Sample code is here:

```
public class JdbcMySQLExample{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YOUR_DB_NAME?useSSL=false";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "root";
    
    String query = "SELECT * from YOUR_TABLE_NAME";

    try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query)) {

        if (rs.next()) {
            
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
          System.out.println(ex);
       
    } 
}
```