# Parsing MYSQL Insert statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm writing a Java tool to parse SQL Queries in order to get table and columns details.
To parse `SELECT` statement I use MySQL JDBC ResultSetMetaData. Something like :

```
 String query = "select * from vendors";
 PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
 ResultSetMetaData meta = pstmt.getMetaData();
 System.out.println(meta);
```

But this doesn't work for `INSERT/UPDATE` statement.

Does someone have a solution to do that?

I tried various other solutions without success.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Getting Data from MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041354/java-getting-data-from-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

you can get the column name of the table using ResultsSetMetaData like this,

```
  ResultSetMetaData rsmd=res.getMetaData();
  int columnCount=rsmd.getColumnCount();
  for (int i = 1; i<= columnCount; i++) {
    columnHeading=columnHeading+"\t"+rsmd.getColumnName(i);

  System.out.println(columnHeading);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. But your solution (what i've already made) doesn't work with INSERT/UDPDATE/DELETE statements.

Comment: search some online tutorials just like, http://come2niks.com/jdbc-insert-update-and-delete-example/